# Titanium emulator could not be opened

Tags: android, android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator

In win 7 x64, Titanium ide, I get this in the console:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.1, Titanium SDK version 3.2.0.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building for target: emulator
[INFO] :   Building for emulator: Galaxy Nexus
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK: 19
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: D:\Android\Keystore (serefbilge)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: D:\Users\serafettin.bilge\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\hello2_mobile\build\android\build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Launching emulator: Galaxy Nexus
[INFO] :   Running: C:\android-sdk-win\tools\emulator.exe "-avd" "Galaxy Nexus" "-port" "5554" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128" "-sdcard" "C:\android-sdk-win\.android\avd\nexus_1.avd\sdcard.img"
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

After getting this error, I tried to run the command as below, then I get the error "PANIC: Could not open: Galaxy Nexus" as seen below. Any advice to solve this problem? [image: Android Emulator Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of digging (I was getting the problem under linux), it appears to have been a problem with the latest android tools, and appears to have been fixed in 3.2.3 of the Titanium SDK. The other solution (which I haven't tried) was to downgrade android tools. Relevant bug reports/links:

- The "official" link to the problem is https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/164116/cannot-start-android-emulator-on-mac-os-x, which pointed here  http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/03/updating-to-android-22-6-1-tools/ (the JIRA bug ticket is here https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16640)
- However, down in the comments, and in the JIRA ticket, was mentioned the **direct download link for the latest SDK (3.2.3 Alpha) required to work http://builds.appcelerator.com/#3_2_X**

To install the newly downloaded SDK, go through Help->Install Titanium SDK->Install from URL, and choose the folder that you downloaded the SDK to.

For running the AVD from the command-line (and to appear as an AVD in Titanium), I had to open the android tools AVD manager (there were no actual AVDs created, only device definitions on the right hand side). I created a device based on a definition, gave it a name etc, then substituted that name into the command line, and it ran fine. However, there was no place to choose that newly-created AVD in the Run Configurations section in Titanium, but it seems this SDK fixes that, and I could see the newly created AVD, and build/run the project against it.

Some other useful things (that may not be necessary now that there seems to be an official fix, but might be useful if you need to use another SDK) were:

- In the official link I posted, the actual fix is to downgrade android tools version (windows download [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r22.3-windows.zip))
- This guy found a config.ini not present when initially building the kitchensink app, and had a temp workaround - http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/160667/emulator-process-exited-with-code-1
- Also in a link I posted above, another suggestion was to install an alternative android emulator called Genymotion - http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2013/11/genymotion-an-android-emulator-you-can-use/. I haven't tried this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I had this same problem. I followed your directions. Well, first I tried to install a different Android SDK (Edit 1: ? ADT maybe), as per the instructions here: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/03/updating-to-android-22-6-1-tools/. That Didn't work, so then I tried installing the 3.2.3 Alpha as you instructed, and now I don't even have an option for Android Emulators (Edit 2 & 3: I have an option for one Android Emulator: "titanium_1_WVGA800" but that gives a similar error as before). Any advice?

Comment: Sorry Travis, have been away from the computer. I'll have a peek over the next few days if you're still having the prob, to remember how it all went, and will post back

Answer (score 0):

OK, a friend finally figured this out. Basically you need to download an older sdk manager and ndk:

1. Download these two things, and unzip them somewhere easy to access

   - Go to
     [http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/03/updating-to-android-r22-6-tools/[1]](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/03/updating-to-android-r22-6-tools/%5b1%5d)
   - scroll down, and click the relevant link under "Download a previous
     version of the Android Tools"
   - Go to
     [https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html[2]](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html%5b2%5d)
   - Download
     the relevant version of the NDK

2.Run the SDK Manager and download API version 15 (DO NOT UPDATE THE MANAGER ITSELF). Uncheck 19.

3.In the console or terminal you can run:

```
$ titanium setup
$ 8
```

4.Select the locations of the sdk and ndk when requested.

5.Go into Titanium Studio Preferences > Studio > Platforms > Android

- make sure the sdk & ndk homes are correct.

6.Go ahead and create a new Emulator just to be safe.